# How to move image to another server PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have two servers so i want when i upload file/image from first server ( using move uploaded file function),
file should be upload to second server.for this i used following code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => '@/path/to/file.txt'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://server2/upload.php');
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

but i want to know that what code should be there in second servers "upload.php".And how can i mention path ?

Answer (score 0):

first off, don't try to upload files with the @ method, it was deprecated in PHP5.5, disabled-by-default in PHP5.6, and **completely removed** in PHP7.0. use [CURLFile](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) to upload files. to mention a path, just add the path as another post variable in the array. as for the receiver, read the [handling file uploads in php article](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) on php.net. finally, consider if you want to let anyone who finds the url to be able to upload any file or not. (probably not, you *probably* want to set a password on uploads), eg

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'file' => new CURLFile('path/to/file.jpg'),
    'path' => '/where/ever/you/want.jpg',
    'password' => 'd540cyLp419rdwelv8c-'
));
```

on the sender and

```
if (! hash_equals(hash('sha256', 'd540cyLp419rdwelv8c-', true), hash('sha256', (string) ($_POST['password'] ?? ''), true))) {
    http_response_code(403); // forbidden
    die("wrong/missing password.");
}
$upload_path = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$requested_file_path = $_POST['path'];
```

on the receiver, again, see the aforementioned "handling file uploads in php" article to learn more.